# Forcing https. on htaccess is returning list of files . How to fix that?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, typo3

Hello we have a website where we need to map every current http page to https to apply the ssl.

If we force SSL  in the site ; the SSL works but  its returning the list of files.

Tried with this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

and this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If we map https to http then the site works fine but they are all non secure page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How to fix that. We want SSL and site both to work properly . The site is build with Typo 3 cms

Additional information
I have found index file and another htaccess files under public_html\site and public_html\site4 folder. The site is not developed by me. So I cannot tell which is the correct index file.  the htacess file under site folder is empty. however the htaccess file under site4 folder has some code in it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

from the cpanel I can see the certificate is valid and installed properly. Can you suggest where to look into for figuring out the issue.

Comment: What is the entrypoint of your application. I mean is there a index.php in your application ? If so in which folder ?

Comment: I am not sure..site is not developed by me..  There is no index file under public_html folder.    But under site and site4 folder i have seen index.php file.  also there are htacess files ... The htaccess file i have edited is situated on the public_html folder.

Comment: I don’t see how this would be a rewrite issue to begin with. This appears to be an issue with your general HTTPS _setup_ for the domain. Something doesn’t seem to be right with your VirtualHost setup for the HTTPS version, so that it only shows the directory listing.

Comment: @04FS  Thanks for the comment. I have added some additional info.  can you suggest where to look to find out the issue.

Comment: Be careful not to provide your domain and internals of the webserver. You have given the domain and your listing shows that there are sources of very old and unsupported versions of TYPO3 on the server, which must be considered insecure. Clean up, as there should be no unneccessary software on a server which always could be a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has anything to do with the http->https redirect.

I guess your https domain is configured differently (different DocumentRoot in Apache's host configuration or a missing VirtualHost for https://.

Your default VirtualHost seems insecure as it allows browsing files that should not be accessible.

Comment: can you suggest where to look to find out the issue. I have added some additional information in the original post

Comment: You seem to be using a hoster and not a self-hosted solution. In that case I would ask them to configure the https:// virtual host to the same DocRoot as the http:// virtual host.

Comment: Sorry to bother again ... We have a dedicated server and whm for managing the host.  Although I have very limited knowledge about server management. Can you include a little detail...Where can I find the virtual host file? I have found this link... https://serverfault.com/questions/303744/serve-http-port-80-and-https-port-443-on-same-virtualhost

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the solution you use. For an Apache server on a Linux system the virtual hosts are configured in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` or `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled`. I don't know if you have access to these files. You should ask in the support channel for that software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

> So I cannot tell which is the correct index file. the htacess file under site folder is empty. however the htaccess file under site4 folder has some code in it

I think your site files are located in the `/site4` subdirectory.

However, it looks like the `DocumentRoot` of the HTTP and HTTPS sites are set differently. eg. HTTPS is set as `/path/to/public_html` and HTTP is set as `/path/to/public_html/site4`. You can access the site at `https://example.com/site4/` (which appears unstyled because it naturally can't find the stylesheets). `http://example.com` appears to have the same content and is styled correctly.

You see the directory listing when navigating to `https://example.com/` because there is nothing in the `public_html` directory (and nor should there be it seems). By disabling directory listings (as mentioned in another answer) you naturally get a 403 Forbidden response.

Ideally you need to set the `DocumentRoot` of both the HTTP and HTTPS sites the same... to point to the `.../site4` subdirectory I suspect. You would then need to restart Apache for the changes to have an effect.

#### Workaround

As a workaround you may be able to edit the `public_html/.htaccess` file to rewrite all requests for the HTTPS document root to the `/site4` subdirectory. However, whether this would actually work or not could still be dependent on your server-side code as the `DocumentRoot` is different.

Try the following in the `public_html/.htaccess` file (comment out any existing directives):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ site4/index.php [L]
```

This *internally rewrites* all requests to `/site4/index.php`.

Providing there is another `.htaccess` file at `/site4/.htaccess` that also contains mod_rewrite directives to route the request then you shouldn't have a rewrite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines in .htaccess for hiding the directory listing

```
# hiding the directory listing
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: It returns a forbidden page with a message - you don't have permission to access this resource .and an additional 403 error